# When are values copied?

Tags: javascript

I know Javascript always passes objects by reference.  But what about the other types?

number - ?
string - Immuteable, so it shouldn't matter
object - ref
array - ?
function - ?
regexp - ?

I came to the conclusion that not all values in Javascript can be objects nor can they be pass by reference with the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/7hh6C/9/):

```
function SomeFunc(func) {
    var numba = 0;
    var innerFunc = function() {
       numba = func(numba);//try commenting me out and switching to next line
        //func(numba);//numba fails to increment
       return numba;
    };
   return innerFunc;
}

//this variable should persist the numba variable through closure.  Incrementing each call by 1.
var closure = SomeFunc(function(numba) {
    numba = numba + 1;
    return numba;
});

document.writeln(closure());
document.writeln(closure());
document.writeln(closure());
```

Because `numba` fails to increment, unless I return the number and updated the variable in closure...then that tells me this is not pass by reference.  Am I missing something?

---

or take the very basic

```
function UpdateNumber(numba) {
    numba = 10;  
   document.writeln('in func number becomes ' + numba);
}

var numba2 = 5;
UpdateNumber(numba2);

document.writeln('back to caller number is ' + numba2);
//in func number becomes 10 
//back to caller number is 5
```

Comment: I emailed Douglas Crockford and his response to this situation is "When you assign to a variable, you are giving the variable a reference.  When you pass a variable as an argument, you are passing the reference the variable holds, never the variable itself."  I believe the issue is simply that I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  JavaScript always passes by value, not by reference.

People often confuse the ability to modify an object in a method and have the modification be visible on the outside as being pass by reference.  This is not the case.  Pass by reference means modifying what the value points to is visible outside the function.  For example

```
var f1 = function (p1) {
  p1 = 42;
};
var x = {};
f1(x);
```

In this example if JavaScript implemented pass by reference then `x === 42` would be true.  However it's not.  The variable `x` would still have the value `{}`

Comment: "Objects are passed around by reference.  They are never copied"  - "Javascript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey the references are still passed by value.  There is a difference between "pass by reference" and "passing a reference by value".  JavaScript does the latter.

Comment: In JavaScript, there is no pointer so pass by reference takes a kind of different meaning...

Comment: @xavierm02 not really. Other languages support the notion of pass by ref without the need for pointers (C# without `unsafe`, F# and VB.Net for example).  The notion of pass by ref can be thought of independently of pointers.  It's a way of passing a location instead of a value.  C++ can do it in lieu of pointers as well.

Comment: I've read a decent amount of books about JS and they all say objects are passed by reference. The fact that you can't change the value of the outer variable doesn't change the fact the object isn't copied.

Comment: @xavierm02 those books are misusing the term then (possibly to simplify things). `Objects` themselves are not actually passed.  Instead references to those objects passed around and those references are indeed passed by value.  If variables were passed by reference then the code I showed above would resolve to a different value.

Comment: @xavierm02, don't believe everything you read on JS Books ;). If you are interested in the topic, read this article:  [ECMA-262 in Detail: Evaluation Strategy](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/) +1 to Jared.

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with saying the object is passed by reference. It means that you don't pass the object itself to the function but a reference to it, which is what happens...

Comment: @xavierm02 In language terms "pass by reference" means that assignments to the object in the callee are visible to the caller.  This is not the case JavaScript which is why it's incorrect to call it "pass by reference".  In language terms it always "passes by value."  It's a subtle but important difference in describing the language

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more productive to think about like this:

- There are mutable (objects, arrays, etc.) and immutable (numbers, booleans, strings) values.
- Parameter passing is always by assignment.
- Assignment to parameters can't be seen outside the function, since you are just changing a local variable to point somewhere else.
- If the object is mutable and you call methods or assign to properties, those changes are seen outside the function (i.e., no copy has been made to the object when it was passed into the function)

*So you don't need to learn if a type is passed by reference, you need to check if it is mutable.*

Answer (score 1):

Every object is passed by reference. And in fact, everything is an object.

```
function addProperty( o ) {
    o.property = 'value';
}

// here, we can see that even numbers are passed by reference
var n = new Number( 1 );
addProperty( n );
console.log( n.property );// 'value'
```

But even though **everything** is passed by reference, for litterals, you can consider that they are passed by value because you can not modify them.

```
var n = 1;
n.property = 'value';
console.log( n.property );// undefined
```

In ES 5, there is this new function `Object.freeze` that makes an object impossible to modify.
Basically, what you're doing when passing a litteral, is passing an immutable object.

```
var n = 1;
var o = Object.create( null );
Object.freeze( o );
doWhatTheFuckYouWant( o );
doWhatTheFuckYouWant( n );
```

In both cases, you can be sure that the function won't change anything to your object because there is nothing that can be changed about the object. Therefore, you just don't care whether it is cloned or not.